# Окна в С++ на основе псевдографики

Tags: dos, окно, c++, visual-c++

Скажите, пожалуйста, как писать такие окна и такой вид в MVC++ 6.

[image]

Вид должен быть как Far Manager и с такими же диалоговыми окнами.

Направьте в нужное русло, где читать и какие книги статьи? Какие библиотеки, API и что для этого надо?

Очень буду благодарен за небольшие исходники.

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите на библиотеку [PDCurses](http://pdcurses.sourceforge.net/) - это аналог [NCurses](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/) для DOS/Windows.

Answer (score 0):

- [Turbo Vision](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turbo_Vision)
- [Текстовый интерфейс пользователя](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/CUI)

Answer (score 0):

А не хотите взять библиотеки Far Manager для своей работы сделайте отдельный форк и пишите себе на здоровье. Я вот помню где-то использовал CDialog вроде оттуда.